# Not getting 'Shared URL' dimension in Google analytics query explorer

Tags: google-analytics

For my project I need to do a query to google analytics to fetch social plugins data. I need to get the 'Shared URL' as secondary dimension. I could select this in Google analytics site. But when I try to create the query from Query explorer, the shared url dimension is not showed under "social". Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

'Shared URL'  used to be ga:socialActivityContentUrl but it was removed from the API I cant see that it was replaced by anything

[Social activities reference](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6205876?hl=en)

> Note: The Social Data Hub is being deprecated. This only affects
> reports that depend directly on the Social Data Hub (Data Hub Activity
> and Trackbacks) and the dimensions and metrics listed below. You will
> still be able to track incoming traffic, conversions, and landing
> pages originating from social platforms as well as social plugin
> buttons used to share social content on your site. 
> On April 30th,
> 2016, the Data Hub Activity and Trackbacks reports will be removed
> from the Analytics user interface. On June 30th, 2016, the dimensions
> and metrics will be removed from the Analytics user interface.
>
> Shared URL 
> ga:socialActivityContentUrl 
> URL shared by the associated social network user.

It is no longer listed as a valid [dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets)

Answer: You cant find it because it has been removed and no longer exists. As far as I can see it was not replaced by anything.